# Laravel - trying to get information from row of same table using self ref FK

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table named `employees` in which exist the following columns:

-`id`

-`firstname`

-`lastname`

-`manager_id`

`manager_id` is the ID of the row that belongs to an employee's manager. So if A is a manager of B, the `manager_id` in B's row would have the `id` of A.

In my `Employee` model, I have the following method:

```
public function manager(){
    return Employee::where('id', $this->manager_id)->first();
}
```

In my view when I try to do the following:

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
<tr>
<td style="width: 12%"><span class="fw-semi-bold">{{ $employee->firstname }}</span></td>
<td style="width: 12%"><span class="fw-semi-bold">{{ $employee->lastname }}</span></td>
<td style="width: 20%"><span class="fw-semi-bold">{{ $employee->manager()->firstname . ' ' . $employee->manager()->lastname }}</span></td></tr>
@endforeach
```

It gives the following error:

### `Trying to get property of non-object`

I have tried to use `manager()->firstname` as well as `manager->firstname` in the view but each time the error is the same.

Comment: I think, in where give '='. May be this will help you.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work unless the employee you currently are looking at is a manager and the manager_id field is empty or null or doesn't match up with anything.

Comment: @omrakhur Please Submit code written in controller

Comment: @AshuJha at the moment there's only `index()` method which has the code `$employees = Employee::all()`

Comment: I've just tested your code and it's working fine.  That error must be on another line or as I said, the employee you are looking at doesn't have a manager, in which case your function returns null which would produce that error.

Comment: `$employees = Employee::all();`
//user is the template name
`return View::make('user')->with($employees );`

You can access the passed data (i.e, $employees) as an array in view.

Please check and let us know

Comment: @user3158900 could you elaborate this as an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you Employee model

```
public function manager()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Manager','manager_id');
}
```

In view

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
<tr>
 <td style="width: 12%"><span class="fw-semi-bold">{{ $employee->firstname }}</span></td>
 <td style="width: 12%"><span class="fw-semi-bold">{{ $employee->lastname }}</span></td>
 <td style="width: 20%"><span class="fw-semi-bold">@if($employee->manager) {{ $employee->firstname }} {{ $employee->lastname  }}@endif</span></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Assuming your Manager.php model within the app directory. if not then please update the namespace in the first arguments of belongsTo() function.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This looks good, I think Employee is the class of the manager as well though.  So it could just be `$this->belongsTo(self::class, 'manager_id')`

Comment: Yes @Jeff you are correct, the class of the manager was Employee. I didn't change the model though. All that was needed was the if clause, as also pointed out by user3158900 above in the comments

Comment: @omrakhur ok cool.  I recommend you do use relations as @Vikash has here, as they have additional benefits like eager loading.  The way you constructed the `manager()` function, you will be using extra database transactions.

Comment: @Jeff, I already have those in the model as well. Just not leaving any stones unturned :)

Answer (score -1):

try this one.,

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\..\Employee', 'manager_id');
}

public function manager()
{
    return $this->managers()->with('manager');
}
```

call the manager function now..
  I think this will help you.

Above will give hierarchy structure answers one inside another one and it will give workers under manager.

If you need only one hierarchy for current record, that is an employee's manager use this below.,

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->belongs('App\..\Employee', 'manager_id');
}
```